# instanceof in Grails

Tags: grails

How to determine Class type of Object in collection?

```
class Human{...}
class Man extends Human{...}
class Women extends Human{...}

def humans = Human.findAll() 
humans.each(){ human ->

    // ??? , it is not work
   if ( human instanceof Man ) { println "Man" }
   if ( human instanceof Woman ) { println "Woman" }
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Tom

Comment: Is humanService.all() definitely returning entries?

Comment: It is in Grail project, I use > Human.findAll()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on your description, I would say you are running into Hibernate proxy objects (ie. class name is: Human_$$*javaassist**). Solution would be to use the GORM provided version of insatnceOf. No need to eager fetch or use a different method.

```
def planet = Planet.get(1)
planet.humans.each(){ human ->
    if (human.instanceOf(Man)) { println "is Man"}
    if (human.instanceOf(Woman)) { println "is Woman"}
}
```

Notice the difference human.instanceOf(Man) rather than human instanceof Man. Use the gorm method rather than the java keyword.

You can see this section of the reference documentation for an [explanation][1]. See subsection "Lazy Single-Ended Associations and Proxies"

[1]: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2.8 Eager and Lazy Fetching

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if it should work.

A couple random thoughts: are your humans correctly built? Maybe they are really not instances of Man or Woman.

You can do some tests using polymorphism:

```
class Human{ ...
  def speak() { println "Human" }
}
class Man extends Human{ ...
  def speak() { println "Man" }
}
class Women extends Human{ ...
  def speak() { println "Woman" }
}
def humans = humanService.all()
humans.each(){ human ->
  human.speak()
}
```

If the last line prints "Human Human Human", then the humans are not correctly built, and they are all human instances, instead of Man / Woman. If it shows an error, then they are something else (like nulls or something)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code above, so my guess is that `Human.findAll()` is returning an empty collection, which would explain why nothing is being printed. Can you try this code instead?

```
class Human{...}
class Man extends Human{...}
class Women extends Human{...}

println "You have ${Human.findAll().size()} humans"
```

If this prints "You have 0 humans", then my guess is correct. If you want to get a list of all instances of `Human`, then it's probably better to use `Human.list()` instead of `Human.findAll()`

Answer (score 1):

in Grails with Hibernate is really problem with instanceof. I have again trouble with it. I find this article:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ProxyVisitorPattern

I mean that trouble is appear when your class has some **relations**.
For example:

```
def planet = Planet.get(1)
planet.humans.each(){ human ->

   //it is not work, see the link above
   if (human instanceof Man) { println "is Man"}
   if (human instanceof Woman) { println "is Woman"}
}
```

Tom

Answer (score 0):

thank for your help. I try your test. Method **speak()** return expected results. 
For Man return "Man", for Woman return "Woman". 
Your test finished ok, but my trouble is always here.

Maybe I forgot get more information:
This code is from **Grails project**. I mean that it is not important.
Exactly I use GORM call:

```
def humans = Human.findAll()
```

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Grails? I just tried this in the Grails 1.2.2 console and it works:

```
new Woman(name: "Julie").save()
new Woman(name: "Xena").save()
new Woman(name: "Mary").save()
new Man(name: "James").save()
new Man(name: "Tony").save(flush: true)

def people = Human.list()
for (p in people) {
    println ">> ${p.name} (${p.getClass()})"

    if (p instanceof Man) println "It's a man"
    if (p instanceof Woman) println "It's a woman"
}
```

Perhaps it's an issue that has been fixed?

Comment: Hi Peter, I use Grails 1.3.1.

Comment: See Tiggerizzy's answer for a solution in Grails 1.3.