# java/groovy/grails instanceof fails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a class called Video and an object of this class (here called "b")

This is the test case:

```
log.debug b
log.debug b.class
log.debug (b.class == Video)
log.debug (b instanceof Video)
log.debug (b.instanceOf(Video))
log.debug (b in Video)
```

the output is:

```
DEBUG NavLinkHelperTagLib  - product.content.Video : 4352
DEBUG NavLinkHelperTagLib  - class product.content.Video
DEBUG NavLinkHelperTagLib  - true
DEBUG NavLinkHelperTagLib  - false
DEBUG NavLinkHelperTagLib  - true
DEBUG NavLinkHelperTagLib  - false
```

Can somebody tell me why the instanceof fails?!

**EDIT:**

I have the feeling that this is GORM related. Here are my donain classes:

```
abstract class Product implements Serializable {

    static hasMany = [additionalContents:AdditionalContent]
}

abstract class AdditionalContent implements Serializable{
    static belongsTo = [product:Product]

}

class Video extends AdditionalContent {
}
```

I think the problem here is lazy loading? But when this is the proxy/lazy problem then normally I would see something like Video$$javaassist when calling .getClass() but I am not seeing this...

Comment: how is instanceOf method implemented?

Comment: this method comes from groovy/grails

Answer (score 1):

This is Hibernate / Gorm related. Your domain object is most likely proxied by Hibernate. Therefore you cannot use Java `instanceOf`.

The Grails team is aware of that problem and therefore they introduce the `instanceOf()` method on every Grails domain object. The following quote is from the [Grails reference](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.1/guide/GORM.html).

> You can protect yourself to a degree from this problem by using the
>   instanceOf method by GORM:
>
> def person = Person.get(1)
>
> assert Pet.list()[0].instanceOf(Dog)

Therefore only compare domain classes by using `instanceOf()` method.

In order to see how `instanceOf` is implemented you need to decompile your `Video` domain class by using [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/).

In a Grails 3 application this is implemented by the trait `GormEntity`.

```
@Traits.TraitBridge(traitClass=GormEntity.class, desc="(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z")
  public boolean instanceOf(Class arg1)
  {
    // Byte code:
    //   0: invokestatic 88 ch/silviowangler/zscsupporter/Game:$getCallSiteArray    ()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
    //   3: astore_2
    //   4: aload_2
    //   5: ldc_w 548
    //   8: aaload
    //   9: ldc -104
    //   11: aload_0
    //   12: aload_1
    //   13: invokeinterface 209 4 0
    //   18: invokestatic 182   org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation:booleanUnbox (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   21: ireturn
    //   22: nop
    //   23: nop
    //   24: nop
    //   25: nop
    //   26: nop
    //   27: nop
    //   28: nop
    //   29: nop
    //   30: athrow
    // Local variable table:
    //   start  length  slot    name    signature
    //   0  22  0   this    Game
    //   0  22  1   arg1    Class
  }
```

This is the only way to understand how the `instanceOf` method behaves.

Comment: mhh yeah. I am aware of that. But I used instanceof everywhere in my project (and is is quite big) and never had problems. First, I don't want to replace all the instanceof keywords with .instanceOf(). Secondly, I need to do a null heck everywhere. I would like to understand WHEN instanceof fails or in other words under which circumstances it fails.

Comment: And. Normall, when Hibernate uses a proxy and you call object.getCLass() you get something like this: Video_$$javaassist* which I am NOT getting. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2975123/921636

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the `instanceof` (I first wrote `instanceOf` but meant the java keyword) fails, but the normal way of checking type is `in`.

`log.debug b in Video`

should return `true`

Comment: please note that the method instanceOf works but not the java keyword instanceof

Comment: That was what I meant. I'll correct the typo. But I still don't understand why it does not work...

Comment: I'll try "in" now. But this is not the "pure" java why right? I'd love to stay in the pure java side when it comes to instanceof. Otherwise I could just use the other two options that I have posted that return true

Comment: "in" returns the same as instanceof --> false