# Grails 3 Not Returning Correct Class

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails3

I have Grails/Groovy code originally developed under Grails 2 and we recently refactored to Grails 3. Running in Intellij IDEA (and on our Tomcat server), a source object that is a DocumentSource doesn't get identified as one. It is instead identified as the base Source class. This code returned the expected results in Grails 2, but has me stumped in Grails 3.

Inspecting the source object in the debugger, the top level fields are null for type and profile and the metaClass is a Source. Drilling down under target->handler, the expected values are found for type, profile, documentId, documentName, and metaClass.

I'm not sure if this is related to GORM/Hibernate. We've experimented with using different version and I'm not sure the impact there. Any ideas?

```
// Base Domain Class
class Source {
    String type
    Profile profile
}

// Extended Domain Class
class DocumentSource extends Source {
    String documentId
    String documentName
}

// Further Extended Domain Class
class DocumentLocatorSource extends DocumentSource {
    String locatorId
}

// Snippet from Service Class
...
sourceReferences.each { sourceReference ->
    def source = sourceReference.source
    MarshalledResponse response = new MarshalledResponse()
    response.sourceId = source.id
    if(source instanceof Source) {
        // Get's here!
        cdsSource.sourceId = source.id
    }
    if(source instanceof DocumentSource) {
        // Never get's here. :-(
        response.documentid = ((DocumentSource)source).documentId
        response.documentname = ((DocumentSource)source).documentName
    }
    if(source instanceof DocumentLocatorSource) {
        response.locatorid = ((DocumentLocatorSource)source).locatorId
    }
}
...
```

Comment: What if you use `source.instanceOf(DocumentSource)`?

Comment: Yup! That works! Pinged a co-worker after I posted this and he had seen this before and we worked through it. I've been working on other unrelated code trying to nail down the right GORM versions and I think this was introduced between Hibernate4 and Hibernate5. Seems to be a duplicate question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896648/java-groovy-grails-instanceof-fails

Comment: The original code used source.class and that seems to suffer from the same issue. Is there a similar workaround to instanceOf() for class?

Comment: I spoke too soon. It blows up later with Cannot cast object 'com.mycompany.myproject.DocumentSource : 2811459' with class 'com.mycompany.myproject.Source_$$_jvst55c_28' to class 'com.mycompany.myproject.DocumentSource'

Comment: Can you reach the desired fields without casting? Doesn't seem like it should be necessary unless you statically typed the variable in the first place.

Comment: Trying: "response.documentid = source.documentId", 
I get: "No such property: documentId for class: com.mycompany.myproject.DocumentSource Possible solutions: documentId"

Comment: Trying: "response.documentid = (source as DocumentSource).documentId", 
I get: "com.mycompany.myproject.Source_$$_jvst627_2a cannot be cast to com.mycompany.myproject.DocumentSource"

Comment: Also, it looks like I have 35 instances of "instanceof" in my Groovy code. About a third of those are for Java primitives, so I'm probably OK, but the rest will probably have to change.

Comment: I had to change the source assignment to "def source = GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy(sourceReference.source)", then I could use the Java instanceof as well as cast